# Trimming specific numbers from Javascript result

Tags: javascript, numbers, trim

I am trying to find a way to trim off the unnecessary number form result.
    An example is having number 123456 - and I need only 3456 shown as result.
    So I need only the last 4 digits of the result.

My code is: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/2drn28c2/][1]

```html
<h1>
Today's Password - Operator ID
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</h1>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = 1
    month[1] = 2
    month[2] = 3
    month[3] = 4
    month[4] = 5
    month[5] = 6
    month[6] = 7
    month[7] = 8
    month[8] = 9
    month[9] = 10
    month[10] = 11
    month[11] = 12
    var d = new Date();
    var n = month[d.getMonth()];
   



 
    var person = prompt("Please enter site number", "4 digits");
 var x = Number(person);
 var y = x.toString();
 var z = y.split("").reverse().join("");
 var aa = Number(z);
 var pass = (aa + n) * n;
 
 
 
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pass;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need an array to adjust the month by one. Just do `var n = d.getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/17wavqty/ try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

> The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string.

```js
console.log("123456".slice(-4));
```

You can also use following `regex`  : `/\d{4}$/g`

```js
console.log("123456".match(/\d{4}$/g))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your Number to String then slice it and cast it back to Number

```js
const numberToSlice = 123456;
console.log(parseInt(numberToSlice.toString(10).slice(-4), 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna solve your problem for you cos it's as simple as ABC.

JavaScript has a [String substr(](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)) method which you can use to trim sections of a string.

Example is

```
let pers = '123456';

pers.substr(-4);
```